# Gravity of a Circular Ring at a co-planar external point.

Tags: integration, geometry

I have a circular ring of unit mass and fixed radius R which lies in the XY plane at point $O$ with coordinates $O:(0,0)$.

I wish to find a formula for the gravitational force at a point $P: (D,0)$ which lies in the same plane as the ring and is at some variable distance D from the ring centre O.

(Note: There are many treatments of the case for a target lying on the axis of the ring.  The  reference so far found nearest to this co-planar case is Problems 5-12, 5-13, (no solutions given) p.127 in [Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems by Jerry B. Marion](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ss43BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=gravitational+force+due+to+a+ring+off-axis&source=bl&ots=-CmJDOiop9&sig=ACfU3U3Yx8GBf2tEu9NVvyYNnk7Vgi7c1Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiws9K2wcDiAhUgRBUIHf-_DX44FBDoATAAegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=gravitational%20force%20due%20to%20a%20ring%20off-axis&f=false).

I expect that the formula should be of the form $F = GM*f(D)$ where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass   and $f$ is some function similar to the Newtonian spherical divergence function $f(D) = \frac{1}{ D^2}$ (where the factor $\frac{1}{4.\pi}$ is absorbed in the value of the constant $G$ ).

So far I have obtained an integral formula by initially modelling the ring as a series of $N$ small point masses of mass $\frac{1}{N}$ separated by angle $\delta\theta$, whose distance from target is $L$ where:

$$L^2 = (D-a)^2+b^2 = D^2-2aD+R^2 = D^2\left(1 -\frac{2a}{D} +\frac{R^2}{D^2}\right)$$

where $a (= R\cos\theta)$ and $b(=R\sin\theta)$ are the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point.

Due to symmetry and vector addition of forces there is no net force in the y-direction and so the effective force contribution (along $x$) for a point is given by multiplying by the cosine factor $(D-a)/L$ thus:-

$$ F = \frac{-GM}{N}\frac{1}{4\pi.L^2}\frac{D-a}{L} 
= \frac{-GM}{ N}  \frac{D-a}{L^3} $$

$$ F = \frac{-GM}{ N}  \frac{D-R\cos\theta}{\left(D^2\left(1 -\frac{2a}{D} +\frac{R^2}{D^2}\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

$$ F = \frac{-GM}{ N}  \frac{D-R\cos\theta}{D^3 \left(1 -\frac{2a}{D} +\frac{R^2}{D^2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

$$ F = \frac{-GM}{ N}  \frac{1-(R/D)\cos\theta}{D^2 \left(1 -\frac{2a}{D} +\frac{R^2}{D^2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

I then obtained the following integral formula for the force exerted on the target point by the ring:-

$$ F = \frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-Q\cos\theta}{\left(1-2Q\cos\theta+Q^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \text{d}\theta$$
where $Q = R/D$.

$$ F = \frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{1}{2\pi}  \frac{1}{(2Q)^{3/2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-Q\cos\theta}
{\left(\frac{Q^2+ 1}{2Q} - \cos\theta\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \text{d}\theta$$

Defining $A = \frac{Q^2+ 1}{2Q}$, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1+-+Q*cos+x)%2F%7B(A-cos+x)%5E(3%2F2)%7D+dx) gives...
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ 1 - Q \cos x}{(A -\cos x)^{3/2}} dx $$

$$=\left[\frac{2}{(A^2-1)\sqrt{A - \cos x}}\left(A^2-1\right)Q\sqrt{\frac{A - \cos x}{A-1}} \operatorname{F}\left(\frac{x}{2}~\big|~\frac{-2}{A-1}\right)-AQ\sin x- (A-1)(AQ-1)\sqrt{\frac{A-\cos x}{A-1}}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{x}{2}~\big|~\frac{2}{1-A}\right)
+\sin x\right]_0^{2\pi}$$

Where $E(x|m)$ is an elliptic integral of the 2nd kind with parameter $m=k^2$, and $F(x|m)$ is an elliptic integral of the 1st kind with parameter $m=k^2$.

Replacing $\cos x$ by $1$ and $\sin x$ by $0$...
$$=\frac{2}{(A^2-1)\sqrt{A -1}}*\left[(A^2-1)Q \operatorname{F}\left(\frac{x}{2}~\big|~\frac{-2}{A-1}\right)-(A-1)(AQ-1) \operatorname{E}\left(\frac{x}{2}~\big|~\frac{-2}{A-1}\right)\right]_0^{2\pi}$$

Cancelling $(A^2-1)$...
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{A -1}}\left[Q\operatorname{F}\left(\frac{x}{2}~\big|~\frac{-2}{A-1}\right) 
- \frac{(AQ-1)}{A+1} \operatorname{E}\left(\frac{x}{2}~\big|~\frac{-2}{A-1}\right)  \right]_0^{2\pi}$$

Being unfamiliar with Elliptic Integrals, this is as far as I can comfortably go at present.

---

After reading the wikipedia article [Elliptic Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), proceeding tentatively, from the definitions of elliptic integrals I think that $E(x|k^2)$ and $F(x|k^2)$ both go to zero when $x$ is zero, thus...

$$=\frac{2Q}{\sqrt{A -1}}\left[\operatorname{F}\left(\pi~\big|~\frac{-2}{A-1}\right)-\frac{(AQ-1)}{AQ+Q} \operatorname{E}\left(\pi~\big|~\frac{-2}{A-1}\right)\right]$$

Next perhaps it would be helpful to reformulate the problem so that the amplitude(?) term in the elliptic integrals changes from $\pi$ to $\pi/2$, thereby making the elliptic integrals "complete" and permitting them to be expressed as power series.  This reformulation could be done by modelling the gravitational effect ($Fx$ component only) of two half rings (positive $y$ and negative $y$), independently, and using respectively the angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ which both range from $0$ to $\pi/2$ but in different directions.

Comment: See, these elliptic integrals are **not** going to vanish by some smart trick. So the only realistic option is to incorporate them into your experience.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin I appreciate your tip and have stumbled ahead a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering similar problems it is usually simpler to consider the potential rather than force. The latter can be found later as the negative of the potential gradient. Assuming the masses of the test point-like body and the ring be $m$ and $M$, respectively, we have in [spherical coordinates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) with the1 origin at the center of the ring and the polar axis directed perpendicular to the plane of the ring:
$$
U({\bf r})=-\frac{GmM}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{r^2+R^2+2rR\sin\phi\cos\theta}},\tag1
$$
where (following the "maths" convention referred to in the Spherical Coordinates link and for consistency with the Question) $r,\phi,\theta $ are radial distance, polar angle, and azimuthal angle of the point ${\bf r}$, and $R$ is the radius of the circle.

The integral $(1)$ can be dealt in the following way:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{r^2+R^2+2rR\sin\phi\cos\theta}}
&=2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{r^2+R^2+2rR\sin\phi\cos\theta}}\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{(r^2+R^2+2rR\sin\phi)-4rR\sin\phi\sin^2\frac\theta2}}\\
&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{r^2+R^2+2rR\sin\phi}}
\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{4rR\sin\phi}{r^2+R^2+2rR\sin\phi}\right),
\end{align}
$$
where we used the convention
$$
\operatorname{K}(m)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}}
$$
for the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Finally
$$
U({\bf r})=-\frac{2GmM}{\pi\sqrt{r^2+R^2+2Rr\sin\phi}}\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{4rR\sin\phi}{r^2+R^2+2rR\sin\phi}\right).\tag2
$$

In the plane of the circle $\phi=\frac\pi2$ and the above equation simplifies to:
$$
U({\bf r})=-\frac{2GmM}{\pi(R+r)}\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{4Rr}{(r+R)^2}\right).
$$

---

To obtain the expression for the acting force recall that:
$$
\nabla f={\partial f \over \partial r}\hat{\mathbf r}
+ {1 \over r}{\partial f \over \partial \phi}\hat{\boldsymbol \phi}
+ {1 \over r\sin\phi}{\partial f \over \partial \theta}\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}.
$$

As the potential $(2)$ does not depend on $\theta$ only two first terms remain.

Tedious but straightforward calculation reveals:
$$\begin{align}
{\bf F}_r&=\frac{GmM}{\pi}\frac{(R^2-r^2)\operatorname{E}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)-y^2\operatorname{K}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}{rxy^2};\tag3\\
{\bf F}_\phi&=\frac{GmM}{\pi}\frac{(R^2+r^2)\operatorname{E}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)-y^2\operatorname{K}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}{rxy^2}\cot\phi,\tag4\\
\end{align}
$$
where $x=\sqrt{R^2+r^2+2Rr\sin\phi},\ y=\sqrt{R^2+r^2-2Rr\sin\phi}$.

Comment: For $r>>R$ and $R$--> $0$ this should presumably tend to the Newtonian formula for the grav potential from a point source at distance $r$ namely $U(r) = 1/r$ which (barring the excess factor 4 in the numerator) your formula appears to do. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you for catching this. Probably the idea to get rid of the physical constants was a bad one, so I have inserted them now. As $\lim_{x\to0}\operatorname{K}(x)=\frac\pi2$, the potential has correct asymptotic $U(r)\sim-\frac{Gm}r$ for $r\gg R$.

Comment: Some notes:- 1. you have used  for angle in XY plane where I used ; 2. You are (generously!) providing a general expression for angles (your) between + and ; 3. The first equation involving  and  comes from geometry; 4. I have editted in an intermediate step, to clarify (for me) how the eqtn in $K$ is derived..

Comment: Also 5. If possible, could you differentiate the potential to give an equation for the force?

Comment: 1. I have added the explanation of the notation and gave a link to an article about spherical coordinate system. 2. Yes, my expression is valid for whole space (excluding the points of the ring). 3. Yes 4. I do not understand which edit do you mean. In fact there were no derivation (except for using simple substitution $\frac\phi2\to\phi$ in the integral, then the definition of $\operatorname{K}(x)$ was used).

Comment: 5. I will so it as soon as I have enough time. I have noticed that you have accepted the answer and then changed the mind. Is it related to this issue?

Comment: 1. Link is where? My point is that I was using $\theta$ for the angle in the XY plane. 4. My edit was awaiting mediation but now I cannot find it anywhere. 5. re acceptance - yes,  sorry; obtaining the force (rather than just the potential) is critical and (for me) the differentiation is non-trivial. It seemed unfair to accept your answer while the other answer does give a force. But your answer is very helpful already.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to press "Save Edits". Now done.

Comment: Thanks. I see that you are using the "physics" notation whereas my question was using (unconsciously) the "math" notation, as does the answer from /u/ComplexButTrivial/.  Would you be averse to me editting your answer to follow the math notation (ie swapping $\theta$ and $\phi$)?

Comment: I see no necessity in the change since it is the ISO convention as well. But if it impoves in your opinion the quality of the answer you are welcome to edit it.

Comment: Thx. Change made. Lets see if it sticks. My last edit was rejected w/o notification.

Comment: Many thanks for the differentiation. I learned the definitions of the spherical unit vectors from the Spherical Coordinates link. I like how your result shows that the  total force is not directed at the centre of the ring unless the target lies in the same XY plane as the source ring.

Comment: @steveOw You are welcome. The force is directed to the center of the ring if the target is on the polar axis as well. N.B. I have corrected the sign of the force in the final expression.

Comment: Re: Polar target - Ah yes, of course.  Also: I have analyzed your final expression for $F_r$ in the case where $\phi=0$,$R=0$ and, with the elliptic intergrals both equalling $\pi/2$ I get $F_r = -GmM/2r^2$ which is 1/2 the proper value. Am I wrong?

Comment: @steveOw Thank you for catching this. Indeed I did not take into account the factor 2 in the numerator of (2). Now bot $F_r$ and $F_\phi$ are corrected.

Comment: Thanks.(Previously I should have written $R=0$ and  = any value).

Comment: With $R>0$, calculating $F_r$ between $\phi=0$ and $\phi=\pi/2$; I get max value when $\phi=0$ and min value when $\phi=\pi/2$. This is the reverse of what I expected. Also the $F_{\phi}$ values look odd (negative and shrinking from $\phi=0$ to $\phi=\pi/2$) - I'd expect something like: $F_{\phi}=0$ at $\phi=0$ and $\phi=\pi/2$ then positive and increasing towards $\phi=\pi/4$

Comment: Did you fix the value of $r$ while calculating $F_r$ and $F_\phi$ between $\phi=0$ and $\phi=\pi/2$? If "yes" what was the value? In my calculation $F_\phi$ is always non-negative. Please check if you correctly used the expression  (4).

Comment: Yes, $r=1000$, also $R=100$ giving $F_r=-GMm*0.000,001,007,571$...(max abs magnitude) at $\phi=0$ and $F_r=-GMm*0.000,000,985,191,768$...(min abs magnitude) at $\phi=\pi/2$. Sorry I gave wrong info about sign of $F_{\phi}$ ...it is always positive. Also $F_{\phi}=$ infinity at $\phi=0$. I'm assuming that (positive) $F_{\phi}$ acts in the direction that $\phi$ increases as it goes from $0$ (z+) to $\pi/2$ (x+). I have checked my code against (4) and it seems right to me.  The Elliptic function code is from the web, I havent checked it thoroughly, maybe some error there.

Comment: Also acc to the formula given [here](https://sciphy.in/gravitational-field-due-to-uniform-ring/) the value of $F_r$ at $\phi=0$ (on the ring axis) should be $F_r = -GMm/r^2 * (1+R^2/r^2)^{-3/2}$ which in this case $= 0.9852e-7$ which is the value my code using your equation (3) gave for $F_r$ at $\phi=pi/2$.  Also I have checked the Elliptic code functions which seem OK to 6 sig figures for arguments between 0.1 and 0.9.

Comment: The equation (3) gives for $\phi=0$ precisely the expression you have cited. Therefore it is surprising that you obtain the corresponding values for $\phi=\pi/2$. The problem is most probably an error in the implementation. Check first if the argument of elliptic integrals is the parameter $m$, rather than elliptic modulus or modular angle.

Comment: You are quite right - I miscoded a sin as a cos. I'm very sorry for wasting your time on that.

Comment: No problem. And your previous remark was correct.

Comment: I have expanded my "answer" to include a third derivation of $F_r$ for $\phi=\pi/2$. (You have already discovered the [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282448/true-1-x-e-left-frac-4x-1-x2-right-2ex2-1-x2kx2-1?noredirect=1#comment6752024_3282448)!)

Answer (score 1):

In order to express the result in terms of complete elliptic integrals, it is easier to compute the gravitational potential $\phi(D)$ first. Then the (radial) field is given by $F(D) = - \phi'(D)$. Following your approach we find
$$ \phi(D) = - \frac{G M}{2 \pi D} \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\sqrt{1 - 2 Q \cos(\theta) + Q^2}} = - \frac{G M}{\pi D} \int \limits_0^{\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\sqrt{1 - 2 Q \cos(\theta) + Q^2}} \, . $$
In the last step we have used the fact that the integral from $0$ to $\pi$ and that from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ have the same value. Now we can write
$$ - \cos(\theta) = \cos(\pi - \theta) = 1 - 2 \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi - \theta}{2}\right) $$
and introduce the new integration variable $\alpha = \frac{\pi - \theta}{2}$ to obtain
$$ \phi(D) = -\frac{2 G M}{\pi D} \int \limits_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d} \alpha}{\sqrt{1 + 2 Q + Q^2 - 4 Q \sin^2(\alpha)}} = -\frac{2 G M}{\pi D} \frac{1}{1+Q} \int \limits_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d} \alpha}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{4 Q}{(1+Q)^2} \sin^2(\alpha)}} \, . $$
But this integral is just the definition of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind and (using the parameter $m = k^2$ as the argument)
$$ \phi(D) = - \frac{2 G M}{\pi D} \frac{1}{1+Q} \operatorname{K}\left(\frac{4 Q}{(1+Q)^2}\right) = - \frac{2 G M}{\pi D} \operatorname{K}(Q^2) = - \frac{2 G M}{\pi D} \operatorname{K}\left(\frac{R^2}{D^2}\right)$$
follows. The final simplification is an application of [Gauss's transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTransformation.html). Taking the derivative we find the field
$$ F(D) = - \frac{2 G M}{\pi(D^2 - R^2)} \operatorname{E}\left(\frac{R^2}{D^2}\right) $$
in terms of the complete elliptic integral of the second kind.

Comment: For $D>>R$ and $R$--> $0$ this should presumably tend to the Newtonian formula for the grav force from a point source at distance $D$ namely $F(D) = 1/D^2$ which (barring the fraction in $\pi$ which is partly due to me forgetting that $\frac{1}{4\pi}$ is included in Newton's $G$) your formula appears to do. Many thanks.

Comment: @steveOw Exactly. You can use the [asymptotic expansion](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE/06/01/04/01/) of $\operatorname{E}$ to find better approximations for large distances.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure how the Gauss Transformation application criteria given in the link is satisfied.  2. Also I'm not clear how that final derivative comes about to produce $(D^2 - R^2)$ and how $K()$--> $E()$.

Comment: @steveOw Take $\alpha = \beta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ in the link. Then the given condition is satisfied, the left-hand side is $(1+x) \operatorname{K}(x^2)$ and the right-hand side equals $\operatorname{K} \left(\frac{4x}{(1+x)^2}\right)$. In order to find the derivative, you can use the equation given [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/20/01/) along with the chain rule and the product rule. The terms containing $\operatorname{K}$ conveniently cancel and only the term with $\operatorname{E}$ remains.

Comment: On finding the derivative, thanks for the tips.  On Gauss's Transformation, thanks for the explanation. I was confused at how in the answer you apply the Transformation AFTER  switching to Elliptic Intergal expression rather than before.  I have laid out an alternative working in a separate answer.

Comment: @steveOw I see what you mean now. It does seem a bit more natural to apply the formula from the link immediately.

Comment: I have expanded my "answer" to include a third derivation of $F_r$ for $\phi=\pi/2$. I have also posted a [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282448/true-1-x-e-left-frac-4x-1-x2-right-2ex2-1-x2kx2-1?noredirect=1#comment6752024_3282448) about the possible identity of the three independent solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution from Analysis of Force (not using Potential)**

$$ 
F =\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}  
\left[  
\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right)}\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{-4R/D }{ \left(1 - \frac{R}{D}\right)^2 }\right)+ 
\frac{1}{(1+\frac{R}{D})}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{-4R/D}{ \left(1 - \frac{R}{D}\right)^2 }\right)
\right].
$$

---

As Question Poster I wanted to derive a solution by working purely with force ($F$) (i.e. not involving Gravitational Potential and thereby avoiding any calculus in having to convert between Force and Potential).

I greatly appreciate the answers from  /u/USER/ and /u/ComplexYetTrivial/ which were developed using a model of the Potential then converting to Force.

All three solutions are presented in different algebraic forms but they give the same results.  The equivalence of the $K()$ components in my equation and that derived from /u/USER/'s answer can be demonstrated using Gauss's Transformation (see Appendix 2 for Details) as follows...

$$
\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right)}\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{-4R/D }{ \left(1 - \frac{R}{D}\right)^2 }\right)
=
\operatorname{K}\left(
\left(\frac{-R }{ D }\right)^2
\right)
=
\operatorname{K}\left(
\left(\frac{+R }{ D }\right)^2
\right)
=
\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)}\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{+4R/D }{ \left(1 + \frac{R}{D}\right)^2 }\right).
$$

The equivalence of the $E()$ components in my equation and that derived from /u/USER/'s answer

$$
 \left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right) ~\operatorname{E}~\left(\frac{-4R/D }{ \left(1 - \frac{R}{D}\right)^2 }\right)
=
 \left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right) ~\operatorname{E}~\left(\frac{+4R/D }{ \left(1 + \frac{R}{D}\right)^2 }\right).
$$

is assumed from the fact that both answers give the same results.  But I have no external validation of this at present from analysis or sources.

The equivalence of the solution by /u/ComplexYetTrivial/ with the other two solutions is also demonstrated here (in absence of full derivation)to my present knowledge only by the fact that it gives the same solution.  If it is correct then the following identities are indicated ([follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282448/true-1-x-e-left-frac-4x-1-x2-right-2ex2-1-x2kx2-1?noredirect=1#comment6752024_3282448)):-

$$
  (1-x ) ~\operatorname{E}~\left(\frac{-4x }{ \left(1 - x\right)^2 }\right)
=
2\operatorname{E}\left(x^2\right)-(1-x^2)\operatorname{K}\left(x^2\right)
=
  (1+x ) ~\operatorname{E}~\left(\frac{+4x }{ \left(1 + x\right)^2 }\right).
$$

---

As a starting point we have the the following integral formula for the net force purely along the $x$ axis acting on the target point towards the ring centre:-

$$ F = \frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-Q\cos\theta}{\left(1-2Q\cos\theta+Q^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \text{d}\theta$$
where $Q = R/D$.

$$ F = \frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{1}{2\pi}  \frac{1}{(2Q)^{3/2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-Q\cos\theta}
{\left(\frac{Q^2+ 1}{2Q} - \cos\theta\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \text{d}\theta$$

Defining $A = \frac{Q^2+ 1}{2Q}$, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1+-+Q*cos+x)%2F%7B(A-cos+x)%5E(3%2F2)%7D+dx) gives...
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ 1 - Q \cos x}{(A -\cos x)^{3/2}} dx $$

$$=\left[
\frac{2}{(A^2-1)\sqrt{A - \cos x}}
\left( 
(A^2-1)Q\sqrt{\frac{A - \cos x}{A-1}} \operatorname{F}\left(\frac{x}{2}~\big|~\frac{-2}{A-1}\right)-AQ\sin x- (A-1)(AQ-1)\sqrt{\frac{A-\cos x}{A-1}}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{x}{2}~\big|~\frac{2}{1-A}\right)
+\sin x
\right)
\right]_0^{2\pi}$$

Where $E(U|m)$ is an incomplete elliptic integral of the 2nd kind and $F(U|m)$ is an incomplete elliptic integral of the 1st kind. In both cases the parameter $U$ is the upper limit of the integration range and the parameter $m$ corresponds to the term $k^2$ in the elliptic integral.
$$ $$
Now the analysis can be simplified if we use Complete Elliptic Integrals. This requires the first parameter ($U$) to have the value $\pi/2$. In this question that can be done by recognising the symmetry either side of the extended line passing through the target and the ring centre.  This allows us to replace 
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ 1 - Q \cos x}{(A -\cos x)^{3/2}} dx ~ \text{ by } ~
  2 \int_0^{\pi}\frac{ 1 - Q \cos x}{(A -\cos x)^{3/2}} dx$$
$$ $$
We then have...
$$ F = \frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{2}{2\pi}  \frac{1}{(2Q)^{3/2}}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1-Q\cos\theta}
{\left(A - \cos\theta\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \text{d}\theta
$$
Next, using the integrand provided by Wolfram Alpha...
$$
F =\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{2}{2\pi}  \frac{1}{(2Q)^{3/2}}
\left[\frac{2}{(A^2-1)\sqrt{A - \cos \theta}}\left(\left(A^2-1\right)Q\sqrt{\frac{A - \cos \theta}{A-1}} \operatorname{F}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}~\big|~\frac{-2}{A-1}\right)-AQ\sin \theta- (A-1)(AQ-1)\sqrt{\frac{A-\cos \theta}{A-1}}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}~\big|~\frac{2}{1-A}\right)
+\sin \theta \right) \right]_0^{\pi}
$$
Let us simplify this expression, using the fact that $\sin(\pi) = \sin(0) = 0$, and cancelling the terms in $\cos\theta$ and some terms in $A$...
$$
F =\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{2}{\pi}  \frac{1}{(2Q)^{3/2}}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{A-1}}
\left[
Q \operatorname{F}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}~\big|~\frac{-2}{A-1}\right)
- \frac{(A-1)(AQ-1)}{(A-1)(A+1)}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}~\big|~\frac{2}{1-A}\right)
\right]_0^{\pi}
$$

For $\theta=0$ the incomplete EI functions return the value $0$. So within the big square brackets we only retain the terms in $\theta=\pi$.  Then for $\theta=\pi$ we can replace the incomplete EI functions E and F by the complete EI functions E and K, giving us...

$$
F =\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{2}{\pi}  \frac{1}{(2Q)^{3/2}}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{A-1}}
\left[Q \operatorname{K}\left(\frac{2}{1-A}\right)+ \frac{(1-AQ)}{(A+1)}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{2}{1-A}\right)
\right]
$$

Now substituting for $A$ where $A = \frac{Q^2+ 1}{2Q}$...
$$
F =\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{2}{\pi}  \frac{1}{(2Q)^{3/2}}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{Q^2+ 1}{2Q}-1}}
\left[Q \operatorname{K}\left(\frac{2}{1-\frac{Q^2+ 1}{2Q}}\right)+ \frac{(1-Q*\frac{Q^2+ 1}{2Q})}{(\frac{Q^2+ 1}{2Q}+1)}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{2}{1-\frac{Q^2+ 1}{2Q}}\right)
\right]
$$
Simplifying...
$$ 
F =\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{2}{\pi}  \frac{1}{(2Q)^{3/2}}  \frac{\sqrt{2Q}}{\sqrt{ Q^2+ 1 -2Q}}
\left[Q \operatorname{K}\left(\frac{4Q}{ 2Q - Q^2 - 1  }\right)+ \frac{(1-\frac{Q^2+ 1}{2})(2Q)}{( Q^2+ 1+2Q)}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{4Q}{ 2Q - Q^2 - 1  }\right)
\right]
$$
Simplifying again...
$$ 
F =\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{2Q}{\pi}  \frac{1}{2Q}  \frac{ 1 }{(1-Q)}
\left[  \operatorname{K}\left(\frac{-4Q}{ 1-2Q + Q^2  }\right)+ \frac{(1-Q^2)}{(1+Q)(1+Q)}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{-4Q}{ 1-2Q + Q^2 }\right)
\right]
$$
Simplifying yet again...
$$ 
F =\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}     \frac{ 1 }{(1-Q)}
\left[  \operatorname{K}\left(\frac{-4Q}{ (1-Q)^2  }\right)+ \frac{(1+Q)(1-Q)}{(1+Q)(1+Q)}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{-4Q}{ (1-Q)^2  }\right)
\right]
$$

And simplifying once more...
$$ 
F =\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}     
\left[  \frac{ 1 }{(1-Q)}\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{-4Q}{ (1-Q)^2  }\right)+ \frac{1}{(1+Q)}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{-4Q}{ (1-Q)^2  }\right)
\right]
$$
Note that it would be possible to apply Gauss's Transformation to the expression in $\operatorname{K}()$. But as the same cannot be done for the expression $\operatorname{E}()$ I shall leave the equation as is for harmonious appearance.

Finally we can replace $Q$ by $R/D$...
$$ 
F =\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}  
\left[  
\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right)}\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{-4R/D }{ \left(1 - \frac{R}{D}\right)^2 }\right)+ 
\frac{1}{(1+\frac{R}{D})}\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{-4R/D}{ \left(1 - \frac{R}{D}\right)^2 }\right)
\right].
$$

---

As a partial check, as $\frac{R}{D}\rightarrow 0$, so...
$$ 
F \rightarrow\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}  
\left[  
 \operatorname{K}\left(0\right)+ 
 \operatorname{E}\left(0\right)
\right]
~ \rightarrow ~
\frac{-GM}{ D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}  
\left[  
 \frac{\pi}{2} +  \frac{\pi}{2} 
\right]
~ \rightarrow ~
\frac{-GM}{ D^2}.
$$

---

Note how the final expression for $F$ is  rather different to that obtained in the answer by /u/ComplexYetTrivial...
$$
F = \frac{-GM}{D^2} \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{R^2}{D^2}\right)} \operatorname{E}\left(\frac{R^2}{D^2}\right).
$$

---

In the answer by /u/USER/ the relevant equation (for $F_{\phi=\pi/2}$) can be converted (see Appendix 1) into the following form:-

$$
=\frac{-GM}{D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}  
\left[ 
\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)} 
\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{4R/D}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)^2}\right)  
+
\frac{ 1}{\left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right)} \operatorname{E}\left(\frac{4R/D}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)^2}\right)
\right]
$$

This converted /u/USER/ solution, compared to the solution here, is identical in the pattern of variables, but different in the details of $+$ and $-$ signs.

---

**Appendix 1 - Converting the relevant /u/USER/ solution**

The converted  /u/USER/ solution is obtained from the form presented by /u/USER/ as follows...

Using $x=\sqrt{D^2+R^2+2DR\sin\phi},\ y=\sqrt{D^2+R^2-2DR\sin\phi}$; for a target in the plane of the ring $\phi=\pi/2$, $\sin\phi = 1$ and so $x=\sqrt{D^2+R^2+2DR}$,and $y=\sqrt{D^2+R^2-2DR}$; and thus...

$$\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right) 
= \left(\frac{x^2- y^2}{x^2}\right) 
= \left(\frac{(D^2+2DR+R^2)- (D^2-2DR+R^2)}{ D^2+2DR+R^2 }\right)
= \left(\frac{4RD}{ D^2+2DR+R^2 }\right)
= \left(\frac{4R}{D~\left(1+\frac{2R}{D}+\frac{R^2}{D^2}\right)}\right)
= \left(\frac{4R/D}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)^2}\right)
$$
1
$$
\operatorname{F}=\frac{-GM}{\pi}\frac{(D^2-R^2) 
\operatorname{E}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)+ y^2 
\operatorname{K}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}{Dxy^2}
$$
2
$$
=\frac{-GM}{\pi x}
\left[ 
 \frac{~D^2~\left(1-\frac{R^2}{D^2}\right) \operatorname{E}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}{D y^2}  
+  \frac{\operatorname{K}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}{D}
\right]
$$
3
$$
=\frac{-GM}{\pi D \sqrt{1+\frac{2R}{D}+\frac{R^2}{D^2}}}
\left[ 
 \frac{D^2~\left(1-\frac{R^2}{D^2}\right) \operatorname{E}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}
 { D^3~(1-\frac{2R}{D}+\frac{R^2}{D^2})  }  
+   \frac{\operatorname{K}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right) } { D }
\right]
$$
4
$$
=\frac{-GM}{D^2} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)}
\left[ 
 \frac{\left(1-\frac{R^2}{D^2}\right) \operatorname{E}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}
 {\left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right)^2}  
+   \operatorname{K}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right) 
\right]
$$
5
$$
=\frac{-GM}{D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}  
\left[ 
 \frac{\left(1-\frac{R^2}{D^2}\right) \operatorname{E}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}
 {\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)  \left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right) \left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right)}  
+   \frac{\operatorname{K}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)} 
\right]
$$
6
$$
=\frac{-GM}{D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}  
\left[ 
 \frac{ \operatorname{E}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}
 {\left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right)}  
+   \frac{\operatorname{K}\left(1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)} 
\right]
$$
7
$$
=\frac{-GM}{D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}  
\left[ 
 \frac{ 1}{\left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right)} \operatorname{E}\left(\frac{4R/D}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)^2}\right)
+ \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)} 
\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{4R/D}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)^2}\right)   
\right]
$$
8
$$
=\frac{-GM}{D^2} \frac{1}{\pi}  
\left[ 
\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)} 
\operatorname{K}\left(\frac{4R/D}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)^2}\right) 
+
 \frac{ 1}{\left(1-\frac{R}{D}\right)} \operatorname{E}\left(\frac{4R/D}{\left(1+\frac{R}{D}\right)^2}\right)  
\right]
$$

---

**Appendix 2 - The Use of Gauss' Transformation with Complete Elliptic Integrals of the First Kind.**

In the answer given by /u/ComplexYetTrivial/  (to whom all credit is due) [Gauss's Transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTransformation.html) is applied. Here are some workings in more detail.

Gauss's Transformation states:-

If:  $$(1+x\sin^2\alpha)\sin\beta=(1+x)\sin\alpha \text{, }$$

Then:$$
 (1+x)\int_0^{\alpha}\frac{\text{d}\phi}{\sqrt{1-x^2sin^2phi}}=\int_0^\beta\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4x}{(1+x)^2}\sin^2\phi}}. 
$$

Taking $\alpha=\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have

$$(1+Q\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2})\sin\frac{\pi}{2}=(1+Q)\sin\frac{\pi}{2}$$

which is true, so then:
$$
 (1+Q)\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\text{d}\phi}{\sqrt{1-Q^2sin^2\phi}}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4Q}{(1+Q)^2}\sin^2\phi}}, $$

Rearranging...
$$
\frac{1}{ (1+Q)}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4Q}{(1+Q)^2}\sin^2\phi}} 
=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\text{d}\phi}{\sqrt{1-Q^2sin^2\phi}}
=  \operatorname{K}(Q^2) .
$$

where $\operatorname{K}$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).