# Find two component infinite-sum formulae whose outputs sum to the Taylor Series of $EllipticE(4x/((1+x)^2))$

Tags: elliptic-integrals

**Function $h$**

The function $h(x)$ can be expressed in several ways.  Firstly it is expressed as:-
$$
h_1(x) = (1+x) \operatorname{E}\left( \frac{4x}{(1+x)^2} \right)
$$
(where $\operatorname{E}$ is a Complete Ellitpic Integral function of the 2nd Kind)

Secondly, by unwrapping the formula for $E()$ we obtain a formula containing an infinite sum for $h(x)$ given by:-
$$
h_2(x) = (1+x)
\frac{\pi}{2} 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[
\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}
\right]^2
\frac{\left( \frac{4x}{(1+x)^2} \right)^{2n}}  {1-2n}.
$$

Thirdly, by expanding $h_2(x)$, $h(x)$ can be expressed as an infinite Taylor Series:-
$$
h_3(x) = \pi 
\left( 
\frac{1x^0}{2}
+\frac{1x^2}{8}
+\frac{1x^4}{128}
+\frac{1x^6}{512}
+\frac{25x^6}{32768}
+ ...
\right)
$$

Also, assuming the truth of a conjectured identity [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282448/true-1-x-e-left-frac-4x-1-x2-right-2ex2x2-1kx2-1?noredirect=1#comment6752024_3282448) and following comment by /u/user at that link, I infer that:- 
$$
h_4(x) = 
\frac{\pi}{2} 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[
\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(2n-1)(n!)^2}
\right]^2~ x^{2n}.
$$

---

**Function $e4$**

I am not presently clear how $h_4(x)$ is obtained from $h_2(x)$. In trying to understand how, I am looking at the simpler function, labelled $e4(x)$, defined by:-

$$e4(x) 
=  \operatorname{E}\left( \frac{4x}{(1+x)^2} \right) 
=
\frac{\pi}{2} 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[
\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}
\right]^2~ \frac{\left( \frac{4x}{(1+x)^2} \right)^{2n}}  {1-2n}.
$$

A Wolfram Alpha expansion of $e4(x)$ suggests that the output series can be neatly split into two component sub-series.  I hypothesize that these two sub-series can be generated by two separate functions: $e4A(x)$ and $e4B(x)$...
$$
e4(x) = e4A(x) + e4B(x)
$$

---

**Question - functions $e4A$ and $e4B$**

I wish to know (or learn of a method for determining) the two specific infinite sum formulae expressions (containing $A(n,x)$ and $B(n,x)$ respectively) which correspond to the functions $e4A(x)$ and $e4B(x)$:-

$$
e4A(x)= \pi 
\left( 
\frac{1x^0}{2}
+\frac{5x^2}{8}
+\frac{81x^4}{128}
+\frac{325x^6}{512}
+\frac{20825x^8}{32768}
+ ... 
\right)
=
\frac{\pi}{2} 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
A(n,x)
$$

$$
e4B(x) = - \pi 
\left( 
\frac{1x^1}{2}
+\frac{5x^3}{8}
+\frac{81x^5}{128}
+\frac{325x^7}{512}
+\frac{20825x^9}{32768}
+ ... 
\right)
=
\frac{\pi}{2} 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
B(n,x).
$$

Comment: I think it might simply be:- $e4A(x) = E(x^2)$ and $e4B(x) = x * E(x^2)$.  Will now go and check it.