# Prove $(1+x ) .K(x)= K\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{(1 + x) }\right)$ using Binomial Series

Tags: binomial-coefficients, elliptic-integrals

**Question**

Prove $(1+x ) .K(x)= K\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{(1 + x) }\right)$ using Binomial Series.

---

**Notes**

1. Here $K()$ is the Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind.
2. The argument convention here follows the wikipedia entry on [Elliptic Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) where $k$ is the elliptic modulus (rather than the paramter $m=k^2$ as used by Wolfram Alpha, Abramowitz & Stegun).

---

**Context**

This identity can be proved simply by invoking [Gauss's Transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTransformation.html).

But I would like to see it proved using Binomial Series to give me some insight into solving a more complicated conjectured identity: $$(1-x ) 2E(x^2)+(x^2-1)K(x^2)=(1+x )E\left(\frac{4x}{(1 + x)^2 }\right)$$ which I am struggling with in [this Stack Exchange Mathematics post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282448/true-1-x-e-left-frac-4x-1-x2-right-2ex2x2-1kx2-1)

**Status**

Calculating a limited number of power series terms by each side of the equation and comparing them by inspection and checking their equality supports the conjecture but does not amount to a proof.

I realize that one valid proof is to show the equality of the binomial coefficients (obtained from each side of the equation) $C_r$ for the term involving $x^r$ where $r$ is any specific power of $x$ (above some small initial values of $r$ for which equality can be confirmed by calculation and inspection).

I also know that a proof can be obtained by induction - i.e. confirming equality for low value(s) of $r$ then proving equality of the differential $dC = C_{r+1}-C_r$.

However I have explored these approaches in my [other SE Math question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282448/true-1-x-e-left-frac-4x-1-x2-right-2ex2x2-1kx2-1) and ended up in a bit of a quagmire.  So it seems that I am missing some tricks.

Comment: Here is how Gauss did it himself. Since $K$ is an even function let's assume that $K(x) =a_0+a_1x^2+a_2x^4+\dots$ and then put this in the desired equation. You can find the coefficients and get the series representation for $K$.See my blog post https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/arithmetic-geometric-mean-of-gauss.html?m=0